# How to establish this result using induction?

Tags: combinatorics, geometry, arithmetic, euclidean-geometry, area

A point $(x,y)$ in the plane is called a lattice point if both coordinates $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Let $P$ be a polygon whose vertices are lattice points. Then the area of $P$ is $I + \frac{1}{2}B - 1$, where $I$ denotes the number of lattice points inside the polygon and $B$ denots the number on the boundary.

How to establish this formula using induction on the number of edges (or otherwise)?

Comment: For reference, this is [Pick's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pick's_theorem)

Comment: Usually the way you prove this is first to show that it is true for orthogonal triangles (triangles with one horizontal and one vertical edge) and then prove that if $P$ is some large polygon and you subdivide $P$ into smaller polygons, and if Pick's theorem holds for the small polygons, then it holds for $P$ also. Then since every polygon can be divided into orthogonal triangles, the result follows.

Comment: The way to do this by induction, if I recall correctly, is to induct on $I$, the number of interior points.  We start with the base case by looking at the polygons that have $I = 0$, which will be the triangles that have one side of length $1$.